# Exit on special button

Tags: java, swing, exit

I have created a custom exit button and i want the code to terminate if that button is pressed. How can i achieve that?

```
String[] button1 = {"exit", "next"};
//if next is pressed
if (code == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
              null, 
              "Knock knock" + "\nWho is there",
              "The Jasmin Project",
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
  int no = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Want to view more?",
              "The Jasmin Project",
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
              null,
              button1,
              button1[0]);
  //end code if exit is pressed            
  if (no == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
     System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
String[] button1 = {"exit", "next"};
```

Try this:

```
String[] button1 = {"next", "exit"};
```

The first option is Yes, the second one is No.